# Bash - How to make running commands more interactive?

Tags: bash

Constantly I find I run bash commands, and keep editing the command (using vi mode) to get it right.

This quite often involves me going back to the command, jumping to places in the middle of the command, and changing things. I can do this pretty fast in vi mode, but still find it slow and error prone.

Sometimes I save commands like this to a file, and edit the file, and run it again, etc, but this got me thinking...

#### Is there a more interactive way to iterate on a bash command? More like a REPL in some way that's easier to edit the inputs to commands?

For example, say I'm iterating on the following command. What's an easy way to update "test", "super" and "java$" without jumping back through the command using vi mode or editing it in a script?

```
$ find . | grep test | grep super | grep java$
```

Another example might be me running a curl against a remote server, and wanting to substitute different args as well. Sometimes I'd set variables, then pass those into the curl, like so:

```
$ curl "http://example.com/$PATH/$PARMS"
```

but I find this is too much searching my history for commands to set variables, etc, as this gets more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure it can be improved, but I just put this together to allow prompts in the middle of commands using subshells. So in the following simple example, it would interactively ask me for 2 parameters every time I ran it, then output that result.

```
$ echo "hi $(ask name), how $(ask old) are you?"
:name (This is a prompt. I supplied "brad" as the value)
:old  (This is another prompt. I supplied "young" as the value)

hi brad, how young are you?
```

If I run it a second time, it remembers what I gave it for inputs (it saves these in a temporary file in `/tmp`). This can be disabled by passing "no" as the 2nd parameter.

```
$ echo "hi $(ask name), how $(ask old) are you?"
:brad (This is a prompt. I supplied "parks" as the value)
:young  (This is another prompt. I hit enter to use the default value)

hi parks, how young are you?
```

#### Note:

- All tmp files can be removed by running `ask clear`
- Help can be displayed by running `ask help`
- This requires bash 4.x, as `read -i` isn't available in older bash's. This is to supply the ask with a default value. You can upgrade bash using homebrew.

Here's the script!

### ask

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
me=$(basename "$0")

show_help()
{
it=$(cat <<EOF
  Prompts you for info, allowing a default value that can also
  be updated by being stored in a tmp file.

  Useful for interactively replacing parts of a bash command 
  you're running with a new value easily, instead of having 
  to manually edit the command all the time.

  usage: $me {default_value} {tmp_key} 

  e.g. 

    $me        -> asks for input

    $me HI     -> asks for input, with "HI" supplied as default value. 
                  Saves the user supplied value in a tmp file, and 
                  uses that as the default the next time it's run

    $me 1 no   -> asks for input, with 1 supplied as default value. 
                  If tmp_key is any value other than "no", will 
                  save the user supplied value in a tmp file, and 
                  use that as the default the next time it's run

    $me clear  -> removes any tmp files that have been created.

  A more real example, the following will curl an url at
  a site, and constantly ask you for the page you want to hit,
  remembering the last value you used in a tmp file.

  $ curl http://httpbin.org/\$($me somePage)
EOF
)
  echo "$it"
  exit
}

# Store tmp files in a folder
tmp_file_path="/tmp/__${me}"
mkdir -p "$tmp_file_path"

prompt=":"

if [ "$1" = "help" ]
then
  show_help
fi
if [ "$1" = "clear" ]
then
  rm -fr "$tmp_file_path"
  echo "Removed any tmp files from $tmp_file_path"
  exit;
fi

# Initialize our default value and tmp file name
default_value=${1:-""}
tmp_key_default=$(echo "$default_value" | head -n1 | tr -cd '[[:alnum:]]._-')
tmp_key=${2:-"no"}
if [ -n "$1" ]
then
  if [ -z "$2" ]
  then
    tmp_key=$tmp_key_default
  fi
fi

# Convert tmp_key to lower case
tmp_key=$(echo "$tmp_key" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')

# Get the default value to prompt with
tmp_file="$tmp_file_path/$tmp_key"
if [ "$tmp_key" != "no" ]
then
  if [ -f "$tmp_file" ]; then
    default_value=$(cat "$tmp_file")
  fi
fi

# Ask the user for input, supplying the default
read -r -e -p "$prompt" -i "$default_value" result
echo "$result"

# Save the new value to a tmp file if we're supposed to
if [ "$tmp_key" != "no" ]
then
  echo "$result" > "$tmp_file"
fi
```